# Запятая при нескольких союзах "и''

Tags: союзы, пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

> Как я узнала потом, муж пришел в
> комнату к дочке и долго сидел рядом с
> ней и просто плакал.

Каким образом в данном предложении расставляются знаки препинания?

**[пришел] и [сидел и плакал]**

**[пришел и сидел] и [плакал]**

**[пришел],[и сидел],[и плакал]**

Такие варианты я вижу.
Или вариант только один, а я ошибаюсь?
Возможен ли вариант без постановки запятой, как в оригинале?

Comment: @verzatrana, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Мне видится 1 вариант без запятой: (пришел) и (сидел и плакал). Если ставить запятые (Ваш 3-й вариант), получится наигранно, неестественно, попробуйте прочитать с паузами: он и пришёл, и сидел, и плакал. Сначала пришёл, потом сидел и плакал.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется верным **только один вариант** без запятых, так как наречие ДОЛГО относится к двум последующим действиям. Поэтому союзом И  соединяются эти сказуемые, а затем эта пара присоединяется к первому сказуемому.

Примеры из условной схемы 2+1: Он прошёл (огонь и воду) и медные трубы. 
На огромном расстоянии разлёгся город  и тихо (пламенел и сверкал) разноцветными огнями.
И стали они (жить да поживать)  да добра наживать.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе все три понимания (а значит, и пунктуации) возможны, но естественным выглядит первый вариант. Остальные - это либо небрежность, либо уж очень своеобразное авторское "чувство текста".

Хотя если представить ситуацию, когда по ситуации надо прийти и сидеть -  а плакать необязательно, то и такое возможно. Посещение могилы, например. Или еврейские поминки. Но тогда я бы оформил ао другому. "Пришел и сидел - и плакал". Или даже в два предложения.